# Epoch time python and excel

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to automate some data processing on an excel file and in the data processing file I use a macro that I guess converts the date column from "mm/dd/yyyy" into the days since January 1, 1900 as per excel convention. So when I try to do a similar thing in Python 2.7.4. It seems to be 2 days off. For example, 2/25/2015 becomes 42060 when done by the excel macro. When I run this code:

```
import datetime

gotDay = datetime.date(2015,2,25)
epoch = datetime.date(1900,1,1)

print((gotDay-epoch).days)
```

I get 42058.

I could totally just add 2 to everything in Python, but I was wondering why this happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is 42058, so there's something wrong w/the excel macro.

My guess is that excel is counting both the start and end date as a day, when really you're only interested in the time *between* those dates.

It's like saying how many days between today and tomorrow. You could say one, which is what python is doing, or you could say 3 (today, the day between, and tomorrow) which is what I'm guessing your excel macro is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but since it came up in google, I wanted to put in an answer. The off-by-two problem is explained like this:

1. One day because 1900-01-01 is day #1, not day #0.  In Excel, if you convert 1900/1/1 into a number, it gives the answer 1, not 0. In python:
   `print((datetime.date(1900,1,1)-datetime.date(1900,1,1)).days)`  = 0.
2. Another day because Excel implemented a bug in Lotus 1-2-3 for backwards compatibility. Apparently, Lotus 1-2-3 incorrectly assumed that 1900 was a leap year. 
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year